# Que obtiene el método indexOf en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda respecto a un método

```
indexOf (value.ser_descripcion.indexOf("@")
```

quisiera saber qué obtiene o que es lo que hace realmente, he leído pero he encontrado 3 definiciones que me confunden  son las siguientes:

1. obtiene el primer índice de la matriz
2. otras que obtiene la posición del elemento a buscar
3. valida que una cadena de encuentre en otra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Método indexOf()**

Tomemos como referencia la siguiente cadena de texto:

```
let texto = "todos los datos son importantes @"
```

La indicación es: Encuentra si el símbolo `@` esta presente en dicha cadena de texto, para lo cual hacemos uso de lo siguiente:

**Uso de `indexOf()`**

**Ejemplo 1, si esta presente**

```
console.log(texto.indexOf("@"))
```

La instrucción anterior nos retorna `32`, siendo la posición del `array` donde se encuentra ubicado dicho elemento.

**Ejemplo 2, no esta presente**

```
console.log(texto.indexOf("arroba"))
```

La instrucción anterior nos devuelve `-1` como indicativo de que dicho elemento no existe dentro de la cadena de texto.

De lo anterior podemos entender que:

- La cadena de texto es tratada como un `arreglo` de una dimensión
- Si el elemento pasado como argumento a la función no existe entonces el valor retornado será `-1`
- Si el elemento pasado como argumento a la función existe, entonces nos mostrarña que posición en el arreglo.

**Método includes()**

Ahora también disponemos de un método más para resolver la necesidad de encontrar la existencia de un elemento dentro de un grupo de valores, como por ejemplo una cadena de texto.

Tenemos de nuevo a la cadena de texto:

```
let texto = "todos los datos son importantes @"
```

La indicación es:

Identifica si el elemento `@` y el elemento `Hola` existen dentro de dicha cadena.

Lo cual logramos de este modo:

```
console.log(texto.includes("@")) // true
console.log(texto.includes("Hola")) //false
```

De lo anterior podemos entender que:

- Si el elemento existe entonces el valor retornado es `true`
- Si el valor no existe entonces el valor retornado es `false`

> Ambos métodos son funcionales para cadenas de texto y arreglos de datos

**último ejemplo**

```js
    let precios = [11.90, 12.30, 23.45, 12.89]
    console.log(precios.includes(11.90))
    console.log(precios.indexOf(11.90))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo muy claro muy completo saludos!

Comment: Listo no sabia donde era, pero ya quedo gracias!